# Check if a string contains substring or part of it

Tags: python, string, find, contains

I want to check if a string contains a substring or part of this substring, like:

```
string = "Hello 13 World"
substring = "01234567890"
print has_part_of_substring(string, substring) # True: "1" and "3" contains on the string
```

Comment: What you want is longest common subsequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more common task would be to find the longest common subsequence, but if you really are trying to do what you say in your question:

> **check if a string contains a substring or part of this substring.**

Consider that this reduces to the following: **At least one character must be in both strings.**

This is trivial if you convert to a set and find the intersection:

```
>>> string = "Hello 13 World"
>>> substring = "01234567890"
>>> bool(set(string) & set(substring))
True
>>> string = 'Hello 13 world'
>>> substring = 'abc'
>>> bool(set(string) & set(substring))
False
```

Answer (score 1):

A [fast method](https://repl.it/G9KL/0):

```
any(chr in string for chr in substring)
```

checks whether each character in the `substring` is in the `string` and exits the moment it finds a match.

Comment: FYI, the inner parentheses are redundant and can be safely removed.

Comment: @ForceBru Good call. Not sure why I expected it to default to a list vs a generator.